# How to get dynamic data in AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I am very new in AMP technology and i am facing an issue related to render dynamic data on click of button. I have created one lightbox with mobile input field. After entering mobile number user should get another lightbox with dynamically generated content and with some icons. Although we can't use javascript on our AMP page so how it can be possible to render dynamically generated output in AMP?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

I have already tried to populate dynamically generated content using API calling but was unable to render on my page.

Expected result : Populate dynamically generated data.
Actual result : Unable to populate data on AMP page

Comment: Could you share your code?